# Getting permission denied error while opening using "vi" or trying excute as "python script1.py"

Tags: unix, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am having an issue where am not able to "vi" or run the script "script1.py",permissions on the file are shown below,i have a different file "script2.py" create by the same user and able to access,only difference is I see "+" at end of permissions for the file am not able to access,can anyone suggest how to make the file "script1.py" open using vi or able to execute the script as "python scrip1.py".p

```
Not able to access below
-rwxr--r--+  1 username users  44198 Sep 15 20:05 script1.py

Able to access below
-rwxr--r--   1 username users  44203 Sep 12 09:01 script2.py
```

Comment: Why don't you try using `root` privileges? Which unix OS do you have?

Answer (score 0):

From Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

```
In some permission systems additional symbols represent additional permission features:
+ (plus) suffix indicates an access control list that can grant additional permissions
```

You can use `setfacl` command to modify access control lists.

Refer these links for details:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setfacl.htm
http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_121/opensuse-security/cha.security.acls.html

Comment: how to get rid of the + permissions?

Comment: i get the erro [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to run the script as "python script1.py"

Comment: Can you paste the output of `getfacl script1.py` and `getfacl script2.py`

Comment: username3@buildserver:/local/mnt/workspace$ getfacl script2.py
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: local/mnt/workspace/gnakkala/Automation/RunCheckOnOpenGerrits_BT_mdm.py
# owner: username1
# group: users
user::rwx
user:username2:rwx               #effective:r--
group::---
mask::r--
other::---

username3@qca-cdit-03:/local/mnt/workspace$ getfacl script2.py
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: local/mnt/workspace/gnakkala/Automation/script2.py
# owner: username1
# group: users
user::rwx
group::r--
other::r--

Comment: you did it only for one file. Can you paste the script1 output?